# Black desktop background , large icons and missing UI components

Tags: unity, gnome, 16.04, touchpad, desktop-environments

Ubuntu Version: 16.04

I had installed Gnome Desktop environment using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`

But when I logged out and tried to switch the Desktop environment, clicking on the Unity logo froze the system, and I was only able to move the mouse cursor. I forced a restart and the same thing happened again.

So I went ahead and logged into my account, but I found these problems:
 1. The laptop touchpad's taps are no longer recognized as clicks, only
    the button-clicks are recognized.
     2. The Desktop background is black and only the section under the Dock is   displaying the wallpaper.[image: 1]
3. The UI of the menus and settings and other parts of the system are shown without any padding, just the plain-text and the system icons have become quite large.[image: 2]

I have tried the following:

Uninstalled all components of Gnome

```
sudo apt-get upgrade and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
unity --reset`
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity compizconfig-settings-manager upstart`
```

And none of these seem to fix the issue(s).
Everything else works fine, I can open the terminal or file manager or the browser.
I do not want to reinstall Ubuntu , please help me fix this mess. Thank you.

Comment: try this `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
`

Comment: @NgocThangPham The desktop background issue is resolved. But the others, such as no borders and padding in buttons and the touchpad issue are still there.

Comment: Please post `gsettings list-recursively | grep thumbnail-size` output

Comment: `com.canonical.Unity.Thumbnailer max-thumbnail-size 1920  

org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size 64  

org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size 64`

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl` + `Mouse scroll wheel` to resize icon size?

Comment: I feel so dumb right now. Actually I hadn't done that, but it happened on its own after the reboot, so I thought it is a part of the same problem. Ctrl+ Scrolling down fixed the icon size problem. Thank you.

Comment: Did your touchpad work?

Comment: My touchpad is working, the problem was and is that tapping doesn't work as a click, only the button click works as a click. Also, the menu/settings without the borders and padding issue is still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41191/discussion-between-ngoc-thang-pham-and-yankee).

Answer (score 2):

1. To active Background use:

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true`

2. Resize icon size use:

`Ctrl` + `Mouse scroll wheel` to resize icon size

3. Touchpad problem can be solved

> Go to **System settings**.
>
> Go to **Mouse and Touchpad.**
>
> Under **Touchpad** options, enable **Tap to click** checkbox.

Comment: Thanks. But `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is already installed and is the latest version. This used to work before the whole Gnome installation and reboot procedure.

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you check it?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Thank you for all the help though.

Comment: Can you join [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41191/discussion-between-ngoc-thang-pham-and-yankee)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and was able to solve it with:

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar display issue recently (no rendering of outline of buttons/checkboxes/tabs, missing padding between UI elements) - basically my UI looked like garbage - easily noticeable in the 'Calculator' app.

I found that if I switched my theme to 'high constrast', then those things rendered properly - if you have the same symptoms, then the same fix can probably be applied - reinstall the default themes (Ambiance & Radiance):

```
sudo apt-get install light-themes
```

You may need to use the unity-tweak-tool to toggle the theme - install it via `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool` if necessary.